# Laptop keyboard malfunctioning, not sure if keyboard itself, the ribbon cable, or motherboard

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure

I am in possession of a Dell Inspiron 1440, and on the built in keyboard only certain keys work (Fine with USB keyboard). I took it apart and used some compressed air to clean it, and then when I reconnected the keyboard, some of the keys were still not working, but they were different keys. For instance the A key worked fine before I took the computer apart, but is now disfunctional, while the X key currently works, but didn't before.

I am not totally sure what this means, whether its the ribbon cable, motherboard, or the notebook itself, and I would love some kind of confirmation on which one is causing the problem is such a thing is available.

Also, I had never taken the computer apart before the keyboard broke the first time around if that help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: At the very least you will need to replace the ribbon cable.  Although it sounds it will be more trouble to replace the keyboard then its worst so my suggestion is just use a USB keyboard.  We have no way of helping you troubleshoot the problem, since a problem like this, is unique to the situation at hand.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a loose connection.  You likely reseated *some* of it.  Try doing what you did again (disconnect/reconnect the keyboard ribbon/cable).  If at all possible try to clean the connection.  However, this may not be possible based on connector type.