# Keyboard and Track Pad Issues After Dissassembly/Cleaning/Repairs

Tags: laptop, keyboard, motherboard, touchpad, laptop-repair

I disassembled my laptop after some possible water damage *([I did not see any](https://superuser.com/questions/1677893/some-keys-of-keyboard-not-working-after-pulling-water) on the motherboard, nor the track-pad chip, but I have not seen the other side of the track-pad PCB in detail [unless maybe the track-pad is surface mounted onto it] nor did I examine the underside of the keyboard that closely, but its supposedly water resilient, and the side of the motherboard its on didn't seem to have water damage)* to clean it/make repairs. Now that I have reassembled it and checked for water damage (thought there was some, but I actually think it was grease) everything seems to be working fine except:

- Some keyboard keys are unresponsive (I can trigger LED's from when I press keys, so I can tell they are not being detected)
- The track-pad is unresponsive

During disassembly I did see a bit of smoke when I had the battery unplugged and I tried to disconnect the display's ribbon cable, but the display seems to be working fine, I suspect it is unrelated.

I opened up the machine again, and checked the contacts on one end of the ribbon cable for the track pad and keyboard to make sure I did not ware on the contacts -- they looked fine. I cleaned them with IPA + a (clean) toothbrush (only used for cleaning things/repairs), and carefully reinserted them, but still no luck (I'm not sure how many times I should [attempt](https://superuser.com/questions/1178472/laptop-keyboard-isnt-working-after-coffee-spill) to [unplug/reset](https://superuser.com/questions/528145/laptop-keyboard-malfunctioning-not-sure-if-keyboard-itself-the-ribbon-cable-o) I don't want to wear out the cable/port). I'm fairly sure this is a hardware and [not a driver/software issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1188479/keyboard-malfunction-certain-keys-dont-work-properly), I dual boot and neither operating system seems to get a response from the track-pad or certain keys (also the key that toggles the track pad on/off works but nothing changes).

In addition to having LED light effects that respond to key-press, I have other effects, and the affected keys ***do*** seem to light up, though the LED controller board does seem to be separate from the keyboard and have a different slot on the motherboard.

One of the ribbon cables seem to make about a 180 degree turn coming from the other side of the mother board, and I am wondering if I flexed it too much and broke it, similar hypothesis for the other one.

External keyboard and mouse work fine.

What should I do to diagnose/what next steps should I take to regain full function of the keyboard + track pad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laptop keyboards are highly engineered so as to be inexpensive. Because of this they are not readily repairable.

The only practical course now that you have issues with it is to replace it. They are usually not terribly expensive.

In the case above you have key press and other problems. Accordingly,  I suggest getting replacement cables for the keyboard as well.

You know the surrounding hardware is OK from trying an external keyboard and mouse.