# Risks With Keeping Internal Keyboard Plugged In Vs. Unplugging

Tags: usb, laptop, keyboard, motherboard, physical-damage

A while ago I seem to have caused a short or some sort of issue with my keyboard ([the post I made about that here for more details](https://superuser.com/questions/1818584/keyboard-and-track-pad-issues-after-dissassembly-cleaning-repairs/1818585?noredirect=1)) when I was examining my motherboard.

I found out I had to replace the whole palm rest to fix it. I continued to use the laptop with the keyboard for a few months. It was still somewhat useful and it made pretty lights.

Then my computer started to turn on, the fans would spin up, the keyboard would light up, but the back-light of the screen would not turn on, and the computer would not post. A few restarts and it would work. But then one day it stopped turning on all together and I had to get the motherboard replaced.

The palm-rest was 400$ to replace so I did not have it replaced. However, I am wondering:

What are the risks of keeping the damaged keyboard + trackpad (assuming there is a short somewhere) plugged into the motherboard vs. unplugging it. Are there any risks in operating the computer without the keyboard plugged in?

Could I expect any potential damage to the mother board from leaving it unplugged?

There are only a couple other things that could have damaged the mobo that I can think of:

- I used an old VGA monitor with the computer, connected through USB-C DisplayPort through a cheap adapter, sometimes it was a bit wonky
- Possibly the wall port I plugged it into not being surge protector
- Something went wrong during the hard shut downs when it was initially having trouble posting?

I understand this is not an opinion site, so I not necessarily asking what the "chances" are (though it would be nice to get a *read* of sorts), more about *what* could go wrong?

Comment: What are the risks of keeping the [internal] keyboard plugged into the motherboard vs. unplugging it.    ...... Keeping the laptop keyboard constantly attached as it should be will not cause any harm.

Comment: @John thank you, I just dont want it to happen again with the new mobo and Im not sure what caused the problem with the previous one

Comment: It's hard to tell without physically examining the PC and checking for shorts. If you have doubts abut the keyboard, and use an external one, unplug it if you wish... but on *a few models* of laptops, you might not be able to do anything in BIOS without an internal keyboard - test before making a permanent decision.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Assuming there was a short (some keys work, some keys do not work), would you say there is a risk of causing a failure on the mobo?

Also, when you say there you may not be able to access the bios, what if you plug it back in (I think I can interact via external keyboard FYI)?

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain - The risk depends on the failure. Someone with the schematic and the failed device could probably determine the exact risk.

Comment: A question that pops up in my mind: can you even power up with the keyboard disconnected? At least on the ThinkPads I own, the power button is part of the keyboard.